# Having problems selecting data from MySQL to PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

I have been following a really good YouTube video on selecting data from my database, however I can't seem to get it right. I can insert no problem, but selecting is causing me real pain.

Can anyone see any issues with this script?

My issue is that the page just goes blank if I try to load it.

It's not a connection issue because I've checked that out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Sam Boyle</h1>

<?php

$mysqli = NEW MySQLi (‘localhost’, ‘xxxx’, ‘xxxx’, ‘cbd_players’);

//Connect to the database
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM squad”);

//Count the returned rows
if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
//Turn results into arrays
     while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
     {

$id = [‘id’];
$firstname = ['firstname'];
$lastname =  ['lastname'];
$squadnumber = ['squadnumber'];
$division = ['division'];
$position = ['position'];
$nationality = ['nationality'];
$games  = ['games'];
$goals = ['goals'];
$assists = ['assists'];
$yellows = ['yellows'];
$reds = ['reds'];

echo “<p>Name: $firstname $lastname</br> Number: $squadnumber </br>Division: $division </br> Position: $position </br> Nationality: $nationality </br>Games played: $games </br>Goals: $goals </br>Assists: $assists </br> Yellow cards: $yellows </br> Red cards: $reds</p>”;

}else {

echo “No information recorded.”
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using 2 different types of ' " ' in the query, which is causing your whole code to mess up. Try changing `$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM squad”);` too `$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM squad");`. You may also have to change the echo aswell

Comment: will you beat me to it by a second

Comment: `$firstname = ['firstname']` does not make any sense here. It creates an array. You want `$firstname = $rows['firstname']` instead. Same obviously for all the other columns too. Though I don't see any sense in assigning each column to a new variable. you can directly use the array elements in the echo statement below.

Comment: And about the quotes: also for single quotes you use two different characters: the quote and the apostrophe (or backtick). Use only `'` and `"`, never `’` or `”` or whatever.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not sure how that happened. Could it be perhaps I wrote half the script of TextEdit and the other on my file manager? I'll change them all and see what happens. Also added the $row's in.

Comment: And sometime I'll copy the backpacks directly from MySQL.

Comment: I've changed every quotation mark (both single and double) so that they are matching and added all the $row's rows so that they look like $firstname = $rows['firstname'];

Comment: @arkascha so if I were to remove the columns how exactly would I go about using this array element? Sorry I'm very new to PHP and MySQL.

Comment: simply `echo "<br>Name: " . $rows['firstname'] . "...";`. There are more sophisticated options, but start with that. I personally prefer that style: `echo sprintf('<br>Name: %s...', $row['firstname']);`.

Comment: I tired all this. Still get the same blank page!

Answer (score 0):

just change this:

```
while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
 {
   $id = [‘id’];
   $firstname = ['firstname'];
   $lastname =  ['lastname'];
```

for this

```
 while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
 {
   $id = $rows["id"];
   $firstname = $rows["firstname"];
   $lastname =  $rows["lastname"];
```

Comment: So basically switch the single quotation marks to double for all the columns?

Comment: try put this inside the while block: echo "<pre>";print_r($rows); what happen?

Comment: have you put $rows in front of fields? not just quotation marks to double! you need to use your variable $rows, like this: $rows["firstname"];

Answer (score 0):

I have made required changes in your code.
Please try.
Also display_error on to get the exact error.

```
<?php
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi ('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'cbd_players');

//Connect to the database
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM squad");

 //Count the returned rows
if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
  //Turn results into arrays
 while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
 {

    $id = $rows['id'];
    $firstname = $rows['firstname'];
    $lastname =  $rows['lastname'];
    $squadnumber = $rows['squadnumber'];
    $division = $rows['division'];
    $position = $rows['position'];
    $nationality = $rows['nationality'];
    $games  = $rows['games'];
    $goals = $rows['goals'];
    $assists = $rows['assists'];
    $yellows = $rows['yellows'];
    $reds = $rows['reds'];

    echo "<p>Name: $firstname $lastname</br> Number: $squadnumber </br>Division: $division </br> Position: $position </br> Nationality: $nationality </br>Games played: $games </br>Goals: $goals </br>Assists: $assists </br> Yellow cards: $yellows </br> Red cards: $reds</p>";
 }
}else {

  echo "No information recorded.";
}


?>
```